# Catch exception inside spring transaction and commit without rollback

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception

Is it possible to catch exception inside spring transaction and commit without rollback?

Comment: Show your example, there can be many cases..

Comment: Can you post your code because one liner question is very difficult to answer.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647507/at-org-hibernate-internal-exceptionconverterimpl-convertcommitexception?noredirect=1#comment96086618_54647507

Comment: @SudhirOjha check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647507/at-org-hibernate-internal-exceptionconverterimpl-convertcommitexception?noredirect=1#comment96086618_54647507

Comment: You could set a SavePoint in sql.

Comment: @PeterRader Please check the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647507/at-org-hibernate-internal-exceptionconverterimpl-convertcommitexception?noredirect=1#comment96086618_54647507

Comment: use **noRollbackFor** and **propagation** attributes  @Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify exceptions to be ignored, in other words the commit will happen.

Example

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = SomeException.class)
```

Doc is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

Or you can just catch the exception, will have the same effect.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647507/at-org-hibernate-internal-exceptionconverterimpl-convertcommitexception?noredirect=1#comment96086618_54647507